# Fatal error frontend otrs 4 while loading index.pl

Tags: perl, otrs

I already installed OTRS 4.0.5 in [rhel6](/questions/tagged/rhel6) after restart [apache](/questions/tagged/apache), [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) and [otrs](/questions/tagged/otrs), while loading http://localhost/otrs/index.pl

The page is not loading and it gives:

> Fatal error- Frontend -OTRS 4

The index page is not opening and I need some help figuring out why.

My error log is

```
[Tue Apr 28 15:23:56 2015] -e: DBI connect('database=otrs;host=127.0.0.1','otrs',...) failed: Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (13) at /opt/otrs//Kernel/System/DB.pm line 184
ERROR: OTRS-CGI-72 Perl: 5.10.1 OS: linux Time: Tue Apr 28 15:23:56 2015

Message: Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (13)

Can't write '/opt/otrs/var/tmp/CacheFileStorable/TemplateProvider/4/f/4fd2983f3605888b9d72424fb64ba2a1': Permission denied

Can't write '/opt/otrs/var/tmp/CacheFileStorable/TemplateProvider/3/9/39285138ef78930f9c3f9d967fbdd6bb': Permission denied

Can't write '/opt/otrs/var/tmp/CacheFileStorable/TemplateProvider/e/7/e73a715153f074752e829500e76f765b': Permission denied

mkdir /opt/otrs/var/tmp/CacheFileStorable/TemplateProvider/3/d: Permission denied at /opt/otrs//Kernel/System/Cache/FileStorable.pm line 88
Can't write '/opt/otrs/var/tmp/CacheFileStorable/TemplateProvider/e/6/e6f4f8c1130924d59deb478d08f08e5e': Permission denied
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Read your webserver error log. You've provided zero information, nobody can help.

Answer (score 1):

You should disable SELinux or add the policy.

To disable SELinux edit */etc/selinux/config* and replace and set **SELINUX=disabled**

Example policy for OTRS is described here:
http://forums.otterhub.org/viewtopic.php?t=20669#p86818

Answer (score 0):

This is SELinux restricting access to the filesystem.  You'll need to set an exception or disable SELinux entirely.

Comment: how would you go about setting an exception?